# Drag String data from My Cocoa App to Third-Party Cocoa App

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, clipboard, pasteboard

I want to drag a row from my tableview and drop it into any other NSTextField in Mac OS X 10.6, and have a string of text be dropped.

Drag and drop already works within my app (between a NSTableView and an NSBrowser), but I have had no success putting any data on the pasteboard that can accepted by apps other than the source application.

Here's the code I tried, which I thought would be enough to get hte word "hello" to be 'pasted' when I drop into some other NSTextField:

```
-(BOOL) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes     toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard {

    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:self];
    [pboard setString:@"hello" forType:NSStringPboardType];

return YES;
```

}

//--

I never get the cursor that shows me the drop will be accepted, and it just doesn't work.

- Things I've tried:

  - Using the 10.5 version of the Pasteboard identifier,
    NSStringPBoardType
  - Using the 10.6 version, NSPasteboardTypeString.
  - Setting the owner = nil, since I'm not providing the data lazily.
  - Using the keyed archiver: [pboard setData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedRootObject:@"Hello!!"]]

None of the above have worked.  I think I have the concepts correct: "Encode data, tell the pasteboard what you've got, then give it the data", but since other apps don't recognize it, I suspect I'm not telling the pasteboard the correct datatype.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks,
Woody

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in your controller class's `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:NO];
    // [tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:YES];

}
```

(This is assuming you have an `IBOutlet` hooked up to your tableView named `tableView`). Be sure to do this in `awakeFromNib` or later. (For example, if you were to try to do this in your controller class's `init` methods, your nib files wouldn't be fully loaded yet, and your `IBOutlet`'s would all be `nil` and the message would have no effect).

By default, most drag operations will be limited to the local application rather than all applications. The `forLocal:` parameter specifies whether you are referring to drag operations that are local to the application (within the same app), or non-local, meaning all applications. The line that's commented out is basically what you already have the tableView doing.

Comment: That's totally it.  Dropped that line in, as you said, and now all engines are go.  Thanks.